# What text editor for Windows or Linux supports Objective-C syntax?

Tags: objective-c, editor

This question might look like a duplicate, but it is not.

I am not looking for a full IDE to program iPhone apps on; I am looking for a text editor for Windows or Linux that recognizes Objective-C syntax. I know NotePad++ does, but it really is painful...

What I need is an editor that

1. auto-completes **braces (not possible with NotePad++)**
2. automatically **inserts a new line** at the end of the file **(not possible with NotePad++)**
3. **highlights** syntax **(possible with NotePad++)**
4. **auto-completes** directives, class names, and/or method names **(not possible with NotePad++)**

Thanks.

Comment: Context sensitive auto-complete is generally beyond the scope of text editors. You may need a full-fledged IDE.

Answer (score 4):

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor does auto bracing and has configurable syntax highlighting.

It also integrates with [ctags](http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?t=3367) to do it's class browsing and code complete.

And since it is scriptable, it should also be possible to write a script to automatically add a line to the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Why the [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) hate?  I use NP++ when I am forced to be using a Windows box.

I always use [VIM](http://www.vim.org/) for everything I code not on Windows though.

Comment: Probably because Notepad++ crashes when you try to switch the language to Objective C:

https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/4618/

Answer (score 1):

emacs FTW!

emacs has an excellent objective-c-mode, can be customized about umpteen bazillion ways, and can be configured to do auto-completion out the wazoo.

I used emacs as my IDE for over a decade on Windows, Linux and predecessors to Mac OS X during the periods of time when Project Builder (Xcode's long gone predecessor) were unusable.

The learning curve is fairly steep, but emacs is truly an astonishingly powerful editor.

Comment: bbum bbum, I'd never expect to hear that you're an emacs user… :-)

Comment: I've never used emcas before, I'll see if vim doing it.. if not I may eventually turning to emcas

Comment: Hah!  Admittedly, I had a rather complex, self-updating, 1.2MB .emacsrc/ at one point.  Then I admitted that I had a problem and nuked it.  Now I'm back to emacs as a relative plebe, with a relatively minimal initialization environment.

Answer (score 1):

Vim. Do I have to say something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in conjunction with [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) and the [clang_complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/wiki) plugin to perform autocompletion of objective-c code. For more info see [here](http://www.zenskg.net/wordpress/?p=199). clang will do a better job of parsing the code than ctags because clang is a compiler that Apple look like switching to, and one of the goals is to improve code completion.

I don't think the clang_complete plugin supports autocomplete braces though. It might be able to be configured to do so.

Comment: Are you using non-Mac OS? If so, How to configure clang on Windows? I just using gnustep and have no idea on how to install any compiler or runtime!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it runs on Windows but the bigger question is why are you trying to do iphone/ios development on Windows? In my example I'm running on a Mac.

Comment: Simply, need to learn some concepts in home to apply on work (where there's a mac project along with mac machine and I don't gonna buy one!)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to try 
[SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/) 2 editor, with [SublimeClang plugin](https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang) which performs autocompletion. Of course, you need a configure that plugin with a set of headers from iPhone SDK then. I am using these tools for GNUstep development, probably they should work for you with iPhone SDK as well.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Komodo IDE for better syntax highlighitng.